# Three Models in One Template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to Django and currently using version 1.11 with Python 3.6.  I have three models in one template.

Model 1 is my custom user which has a primary key called formattedusername.

Model 2 is my access list which has a should create a 1 to many relationship with User on ntname.  Model two has a foreign key to the reference table ReportList called report_id.

Model 3 is my report list which has report_id as a primary key.

I'm trying to create a views.py to link all three tables for one template.  In my template I want to display for the current User all report_names listed in my access list model. Then another display of all available reports that the current User doesn't have access to, so the reports in Report List that don't exist in Access List.

```
For my views.py I tried several variations of the following:

def applicationdetail(request, ntname):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=formattedusername)
    applicationlist = QvReportList.objects.all()
    applicationaccess = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(user=ntname)
    context = {'user' : request.user, 'applicationdetail' : applicationaccess}
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', context=context)



class IndexView(User):
    context_object_name = 'profile_list'
    template_name = 'contacts/index.html'
    queryset = User.objects.all()

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['users'] = User.objects.filter(formattedusername=formattedusername)
    context['reportaccess'] = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname=ntname)
    context['reportlist'] = QvReportList.objects.all()
    # And so on for more models
    return context
```

For my template to get user information and current access I'm using the following, but for some reason I'm unable to get the application to return the correct data (report_name) that exists in the database, for the next step i'd like to have all reports that aren't in reportaccess:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

  {% block head %}
  <title> Profile </title>
  {% endblock %}

  {% block body %}
<div class = "container">


      <h2>{{ user.username }}</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Email: {{ user.email }}</li>
        <li>Employee First Name: {{ user.first_name }}</li>
        <li>Employee Last Name: {{ user.last_name }}</li>
        <li>Coid: {{ user.coid }}</li>
        <li>Facility: {{ user.facility }}</li>
        <li>Job Description: {{ user.jobdescription }}</li>
        <li>Position Description: {{ user.positiondescription }}</li>
      </ul>


</div>

<div class = "container">


      <h2>Current Access Application List</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Application Name: {% for app in applicationdetail %}
             <input type="checkbox" name="report_name" value="{{ app.report_name }}" /> {{ app.report_name }}<br />
        {% endfor %}
        </li>

      </ul>


</div>
  {% endblock %}
```

Attached below is my model using graphviz

[image: Graphviz Data Model]

Below is the models code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin)
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.forms import ModelForm


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):



    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
    formattedusername = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, primary_key = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    facility = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    jobdescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    positiondescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    coid = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    streetaddress = models.CharField(max_length=140)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'accounts'
        db_table = "user"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.formattedusername = '{domain}\{username}'.format(
            domain='HCA', username=self.username)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs);


#    REQUIRED_FIELDS = "username"

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)


class QvReportList(models.Model):
    report_id = models.CharField(db_column='Report_ID',primary_key=True, max_length=100, serialize=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_name = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Name', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_name_sc = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Name_SC', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    qv_filename = models.CharField(db_column='QV_FileName', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_access = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Access', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_group_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Report_Group_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_sub_group_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Report_Sub_Group_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    qv_dept_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='QV_Dept_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    qv_dept_desc = models.CharField(db_column='QV_Dept_Desc', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    load_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Load_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    approver_fname = models.CharField(db_column='Approver_FName', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    approver_lname = models.CharField(db_column='Approver_LName', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    approver_ntname = models.CharField(db_column='Approver_NTName', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    beg_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Beg_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='End_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    active = models.IntegerField(db_column='Active', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    approval_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Approval_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    role_based_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Role_Based_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'QV_Report_List'


class QVReportAccess(models.Model):
    user_status = models.CharField(db_column='User_Status', max_length = 20)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ntname = models.OneToOneField(User,db_column='NTName', max_length=7,primary_key=True, serialize=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_name = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_name_sc = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Name_SC', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    datareduce_report_code = models.IntegerField(db_column='DataReduce_Report_Code', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    role_based_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Role_Based_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_id = models.OneToOneField(QvReportList,db_column='Report_ID', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_group_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Report_Group_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_access = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Access', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sr_datareduce_summary_code = models.CharField(db_column='SR_DataReduce_Summary_Code', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sr_datareduce_patient_code = models.CharField(db_column='SR_DataReduce_Patient_Code', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    userid = models.IntegerField(db_column='UserID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    user_group_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='User_Group_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    access_level_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Active', blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.IntegerField(db_column='Access_Level_ID', blank=True, null=True)
    qv_statusid = models.IntegerField(db_column='QV_StatusID', blank=True, null=True)
    employee_status_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Employee_Status_ID', blank = True, null = True)
    new_user = models.IntegerField(db_column='New_User', blank = True, null = True)
    new_access = models.IntegerField(db_column='New_Access', blank = True, null = True)
    new_report = models.IntegerField(db_column='New_Report', blank = True, null = True)
    changed_row = models.IntegerField(db_column='Changed_Row',blank = True, null = True)
    last_changed_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Last_Changed_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    access_beg_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Access_Beg_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    access_end_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Access_End_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_beg_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Report_Beg_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_end_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Report_End_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    qv_startdate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='QV_StartDate', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    load_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Load_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'QV_ReportAccess'
```

Comment: Post the code of your models instead of describing them.

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: Your QVReportAccess model doesn't have a field named user.  Perhaps the line where you populate application access should read: `applicationaccess = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname=ntname)`

Comment: I changed it, but that's not working.  I'm thinking it's something to do with my user =  since formattedusername is defined in my model it isn't defined here, but i'm not sure how to add HCA\{username} here.

Comment: I tried user = User.objects.filter(formattedusername=formattedusername), but that didn't work either.  I don't think i'm understanding correctly how the views.py should work.

Comment: In the view, formattedusername doesn't seem to be defined.  If the user you want to filter on is always the current logged in user, rather than querying with some known info, you can use FBV: `request.user` or CBV `self.request.user`

An easy way to see what is happening is to print(something) to verify the data you expect exists inside your functions.  Also, temporarily wrapping the contents of your function inside a try/except block can help nail down an issue.  ex:

`def applicationdetail(request, ntname):
    try:
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)`

Comment: How can I get Domain\ prior to self.request.user?  The domain can be hard coded as a string since it will never.

Comment: You could add it as a new field to your User model with a default of the standard domain, and then access with `request.user.domain`

Comment: I already have formattedusername defined in my model as:     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.formattedusername = '{domain}\{username}'.format(
            domain='HCA', username=self.username)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to to my formatteduser name not being defined. L. Long's response helped clarify the issue.